# Datetimepicker didn't recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#

I don't know why i got this error message:
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
if(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerDateEnd.Text) <= Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerDateStart.Text)){do something....}
```

in the datetimepicker property,I use CustomFormat:MM-dd-yyyy and Format:Custom.

Comment: The object may already be a DateTime().  Convert expect object to be a string.

Comment: just use `DateTimePicker's` `Value` property instead of converting text to `DateTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Value:

```
if(dateTimePickerDateEnd.Value <= dateTimePickerDateStart.Value)
{
    //do something....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert it, use `.Value` [instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(dateTimePickerDateEnd.Value <= dateTimePickerDateStart.Value)
```